# Negative-margin border on an element that is centered with margin: 0 auto;

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I have a fixed-width page that I want to add a simple border to with the Border CSS command. However, I don't want this border to balloon the page and cause smaller screens to have a horizontal scrollbar. I'm not too great with CSS, but I know enough that I looked into using negative margins to offset the border's width since I had already done something similar to add borders to other elements that I don't want moving. But when I do so on my main container div, everything gets thrown off-center and smashed up to the left side of the page. I'm using the Blueprint CSS framework and I figured there was something in there that was messing with my margins, and I found the main container is applied a "Margin: 0 auto;" to center it on the page.

So, I ask now, how the hell can I apply a negative-margin border to a page while still centering the layout on-screen? I've tried to wrap the container in a div and apply the border and negative-margin to it, but no dice, I tried nesting a div inside the container and applying the border to the container, but that went badly as well. Somebody throw me a bone here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the negative margin is working, you can get the centering back by adding a wrapper div with a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto`.

In my testing, the negative margin didn't change the width of the box. A few other strategies:

1. Adjust the width of your div to offset the width added by the borders.
2. Add a background image to the div that simulates left and right borders.
3. Use JavaScript to detect the width of the window and remove the border when necessary.
4. Add `body { overflow-x: hidden }` to suppress the horizontal scrollbar.
5. Use a [CSS3 media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width) to add the border only when there's enough room (optionally falling back to JavaScript (see #3) for older browsers).

**Update:** Instead of negative margins, you can probably use [box-sizing: border-box](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) so that the border doesn't add to the element's width in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean that I should have 2 wrappers then for my container? Because what you're suggesting I think maybe is to add a single wrapper, but this makes a mess of things!

Comment: @Milo One wrapper, but I didn't have much luck with that either, so I moved on to other ideas.  None of the suggestions 1-5 require adding anything to the HTML. Do any of those make sense? 4 is the simplest. 5 is probably the best, albeit most advanced.

Comment: I understand #1, but this is not possible since I am using all of the space inside of the page and can't afford to scrunch it further just for a border. Adding a background image is basically the same as 1 as it would require me to move content inside of my page to allow the image to be visible. 3, I'm not familiar with JavaScript and I don't think I will invest time in it just for the sake of a page border. 5 is also a bit too complicated I think. 4 seems interesting but I don't understand the implications - would this mean that the horizontal scrollbar will never appear no matter what?